# Converting IQueryable<T> to List<T> using EF core with postgres DB

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, npgsql

I am using a postgres DB and EF core. I have the following code get data using DB context

```
IQueryable<string> projectIds = context.Projects.Where(x => x.Collaborators.Contains(userId)).Select(x => x.Id);
List<string> ids = projectIds.ToList();
```

When I execute `projectIds.ToList()`, I get the exception (copied below).

What is the right way of using IQueryable? Or is there any other way to convert IQueryable to List?

Any suggestions would help a lot..

Exception details:

````
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=42883: operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]
  Source=Npgsql
  StackTrace:
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__44.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteReader>d__100.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteReader>d__100.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)```
````

Comment: Can you show your entity classes?

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: The problem is not `ToList()` it's likely something in the previous line. `ToList()` only caused the `IQueryable` to be queried/enumerated. I'm guessing that `.Contains()` is causing some broken SQL to be generated that postgresql doesn't understand.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I use PostgreSQL verison 14

Comment: Show generated SQL. But looks like a bug in Npgsql EF Core provider. Which version do you use?

Comment: Interesting, what array is doing here. Show your model and mapping.

Comment: Update question, not comment.

Comment: Anyway, looks like `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` incorrectly generated parameter.

Comment: Please provide a full code sample, including the model and its configuration; the code above should definitely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions in comments.
After hours of trial found out that the error was not during converting to ToList().

The error lies with using `contains` operator on `Character varying[]`

[Not sure, if it is any kind of bug]

Modifying the `Character varying[]` array to `text[]` in postgres fixed the issue.